# Finding mean and median in constant time

Tags: java, algorithm, data-structures

This is a common interview question. 
You have a stream of numbers coming in (let's say more than a million). The numbers are between [0-999]).

```
Implement a class which supports three methods in O(1) 

* insert(int i); 
* getMean(); 
* getMedian();
```

This is my code.

```
public class FindAverage {

  private int[] store;
  private long size;
  private long total;
  private int highestIndex;
  private int lowestIndex;

  public FindAverage() {
    store  = new int[1000];
    size = 0;
    total = 0;
    highestIndex = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
    lowestIndex = Integer.MAX_VALUE;

  }

  public void insert(int item) throws OutOfRangeException {
    if(item < 0 || item > 999){
      throw new OutOfRangeException();
    }
    store[item] ++;
    size ++;
    total += item;
    highestIndex = Integer.max(highestIndex, item);
    lowestIndex = Integer.min(lowestIndex, item);
  }

  public float getMean(){
    return (float)total/size;
  }

  public float getMedian(){

  }
}
```

I can't seem to think of a way to get the median in O(1) time.
Any help appreciated.

Comment: Why can't you update median (saved as (value, number among values)) on `insert` just as you do with `total`?

Comment: Given your `store` has a fixed (1000) number of elements, nearly any code you write to compute the median will be O(1).

Comment: @PaulHankin it doesn't have a fixed number of elements. You might want to read the question again.

Comment: @Abstraction That's what I'm trying to do, but can't seem to find a way to.

Comment: @MelissaStewart Paul is right, `store` has fixed number of elements (1000). Doesn't matter how many values are inserted. See [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/43073372/5221149).

Comment: @MelissaStewart your initialization `store  = new int[1000];` guarantees that `store` has a fixed number of elements. You might want to read your code again.

Answer (score 10):

You have already done all the heavy lifting, by building the `store` counters. Together with the `size` value, it's easy enough.

You simply start iterating the `store`, summing up the counts until you reach half of `size`. That is your median value, if `size` is odd. For even `size`, you'll grab the two surrounding values and get their average.

Performance is *O(1000/2)* on average, which means *O(1)*, since it doesn't depend on `n`, i.e. performance is unchanged even if `n` reaches into the billions.

Remember, *O(1)* doesn't mean instant, or even fast. As [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_complexity#Constant_time) says it:

> An algorithm is said to be constant time (also written as *O(1)* time) if the value of T(n) is **bounded by a value that does not depend on the size of the input**.

In your case, that bound is 1000.

Comment: It's nitpicky maybe, but O(1) doesn't mean unrelated to `n`. For example, `for (i = 0; i < n % 10000; i++) putchar('.');` is O(1) since it never outputs more than 10000 items, but the runtime depends on `n` (specifically, `n` modulo 10000).

Comment: Maybe I'm not understanding you, but iterating a list doesn't make the algorithm O(1) right.

Comment: @MelissaStewart iterating over a list of bounded size is O(1). Doing 1000 things is a constant amount of work, so O(1).

Comment: @PaulHankin ok that helps, I can think of a way to use that.

Comment: "if n reaches into the billions" - the value will be 1000000000/2. So it is bound to n as n in this case is 1000. And we would get linear time, not constant

Comment: @AlexVovchuk *"n in this case is 1000"* No, `n` is the number of inputs, aka the number of items inserted, aka the value of `size`, not the length of the `store` array, which is always 1000. That is why `getMedian()` has a time complexity of _O(1)_, since the performance of making that call is unrelated to `n`, same as the `insert()` and `getMean()` method performance is unrelated to the number of inputs.

Answer (score 3):

The possible values that you can read are quite limited - just 1000. So you can think of implementing something like a [counting sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Counting_sort) - each time a number is input you increase the counter for that value.

To implement the median in constant time, you will need two numbers - the median index(i.e. the value of the median) and the number of values you've read and that are on the left(or right) of the median. I will just stop here hoping you will be able to figure out how to continue on your own.

EDIT(as pointed out in the comments): you already have the array with the sorted elements(`stored`) and you know the number of elements to the left of the median(`size/2`). You only need to glue the logic together. I would like to point out that if you use linear additional memory you won't need to iterate over the whole array on each insert.

Comment: Code in question already has the counters you're talking about in the first paragraph. See field `store`.

Comment: @Andreas it is missing one of the values - the number of values on the left(or right) to the median. Using that(and a bit of thinking) we do not need to iterate over all possible values

Comment: Doesn't matter. That can be done in the `getMedian()` method. Iterating the `store` array is constant time, relative to `n`.

Comment: Yes it is. And the constant is 1000-ish. Using my suggestion it can be significantly optimized

Comment: @Andreas actually you are right. A second value is not needed

Answer (score 2):

**For the general case**, where range of elements is unlimited, **such data structure does not exist** based on any comparisons based algorithm, as it will allow `O(n)` sorting.

Proof: Assume such DS exist, let it be `D`. 

Let `A` be input array for sorting. (Assume `A.size()` is even for simplicity, that can be relaxed pretty easily by adding a garbage element and discarding it later).

```
sort(A):
  ds = new D()
  for each x in A:
    ds.add(x)
  m1 = min(A) - 1
  m2 = max(A) + 1
  for (i=0; i < A.size(); i++):
    ds.add(m1)
  # at this point, ds.median() is smallest element in A
  for (i = 0; i < A.size(); i++):
    yield ds.median()
    # Each two insertions advances median by 1
    ds.add(m2)
    ds.add(m2)
```

Claim 1: This algorithm runs in `O(n)`.

Proof: Since we have constant operations of add() and median(), each of them is `O(1)` per iteration, and the number of iterations is linear - the complexity is linear.

Claim 2: The output is sorted(A).

Proof (guidelines): After inserting n times `m1`, the median is the smallest element in `A`. Each two insertions after it advances the median by one item, and since the advance is sorted, the total output is sorted.

Since the above algorithm sorts in `O(n)`, and not possible under comparisons model, such DS does not exist.

QED.

Comment: your proof is completely divergent off the scope of the question, but super elegant nonetheless.

Comment: @MelissaStewart Updated the solution to catch wider range of computation models (reduction from sorting instead of from element distinctness).

Comment: @amit The point is that since there are only 1000 possible values, we are NOT in the general case.

Comment: Why are you talking about sorting?  Are you implying that finding the median in O(n) is impossible in the general case?  Quickselect yields O(n) average-case median selection.